# How can I disable "Simulate Secondary Display" when the simulated secondary display prevents me from reaching the button?

Tags: settings, screen, developer-options, smartwatch

**My Question will get more information over time.**

I got a smartwatch (h1-c-aladeng) on my birthday, I very love it but I make a serious problem that I can't fix.

Its specification:

- Screen resolution is 240x240, very hard to read and type on a keyboard, and a slight misalignment of the touch screen.
- Running Android 9.0.
- The model (display in "Find My Device"): Lanix Ilium LT510

My problem:

- A lot of features have been turned off. That is why I use the developer option and turned some features back on, but I accidentally touched "simulate secondary display" and put a display on the screen, The "Simulate Screen" blocked the screen, and I can't reach the "none" option in the setting.
- During that time I have USB Debugging turned on and "always allow this computer". After that, I accidentally turned the developer option off, I turned it right back on and I didn't know that action will clear all the authorized computers connected to it.

Before authorized cleared:

- I can still use ADB, recovery mode, but it just shows "No Command" and auto restart.
- Boot to fastboot makes it put the "fastboot" on the screen after that it just auto restarts. I try anything I can't make it disappear.

I'm stuck with a second screen. and there is a way I can turn it off?

More:

- I don't think I can get the answer but I will still waiting...
- I have tried to factory reset like *[here](https://www.verizon.com/support/knowledge-base-219178/)* but it is in a different way I think.
- Is there no way to factory reset it with just one physical button?
- I think this watch doesn't have a real screen, it is likely this screen is just a small monitor like a PC and has software simulate it because it has too much delay like I'm going to left. It needs to be around 0.5 seconds to actually go into my point. It doesn't behave like a real phone that has mostly no delay.
- I have searched and there is a mode called EDL mode but I didn't know how to access it.
- I have an idea. I can connect to my phone using a micro-to-type C USB cable. Is there an app that can config the option of the OTG device?
- I am able to make the "Restore factory settings" tab pop up by pressing the button multiple time but I wasn't able to touch the "confirm" button:

  [image: Restore factory settings]
- I open up my watch (don't worry my warranty is still there I didn't scratch anything) and here is the circuit in that:

  [image: The watch circuit]

Comment: Please is there anyone that can help me in this situation? I can't do anything, why does USB debugging need an authorizer I just allow this computer before. I can't use any wipe tool. please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Give [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) a try if possible, might just work! It shows whatever resolution you tell it to. scrcpy is very versatile and can allow you to play with the options (via --help) to get the button you need pressed. For instance, MOD+f enables fullscreen mode. etc etc. There's also [guiscrcpy](https://github.com/srevinsaju/guiscrcpy) if you want a graphical front-end.

Comment: the resolution of my watch is 240x240
by the way is there any code that can disable the "simulate secondary display" or development option?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to disable the display overlay via ADB

```
adb shell settings put global overlay_display_devices null
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).