# Smartwatch: forcing a factory reset without USB debugging?

Tags: adb, factory-reset, usb-debugging, developer-options, smartwatch

I recently made a mistake on my watch "h1-c-aladeng"(watch model) or "Lanix Ilium LT510"(the model in "Find My Device"). I now can look at the smartwatch and can't do anything like "[here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/247874/how-can-i-disable-simulate-secondary-display-when-the-simulated-secondary-disp)".

Right now I want to know if I'm still able to save my smartwatch by factory resetting it. by the way, It has only 1 physical button that works like a home/power button. When pressed multiple times it pops a "reset setting" window on the screen but can't press the confirm button.

It doesn't have USB debugging turned on, so I can't use ADB to reset. I search on the web for some tools but can't help either. so is there a way I can factory reset my smartwatch without USB debugging?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disable "Simulate Secondary Display" when the simulated secondary display prevents me from reaching the button?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/247874/how-can-i-disable-simulate-secondary-display-when-the-simulated-secondary-disp)